# How to treat rows with certain common columns as same row when iterating the result?

Tags: php

My query result returns an array that contains rows with company's structure (group/department/team) as columns and several other data columns, for example:

```
[
    0 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => null,
        data_col1 => "some_data1",     
        data_col2 => "some_data2"
    ],
    1 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => null,
        data_col1 => "some_data3",
        data_col2 => "some_data4"     
    ],
    2 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => "t3",
        data_col1 => "some_data5",
        data_col2 => "some_data6"     
    3 => [
        group => "g4",
        department => "d6",
        team => "t11",
        data_col1 => "some_data7"
        data_col2 => "some_data8"    
    ]
]
```

I want to "group" the results into an array with common group/department/team so that I can treat all the results with common group/department/team as single row and get the data from them in the same iteration.

The expected structure would be similar to:

```
[
    0 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => null,
        data => [
            0 => [data_col1 => "some_data1", data_col2 => "some_data2"],     
            1 => [data_col1 => "some_data3", data_col2 => "some_data4"]
    ],
    1 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => "t3",
        data => [
            0 => [data_col1 => "some_data5", data_col2 => "some_data6"]                   
    ],  
    2 => [
        group => "g4",
        department => "d6",
        team => "t11",
        data => [
            0 => [data_col1 => "some_data7", data_col2 => "some_data8"]
    ]
]
```

How can I convert the original array to the desired one, or it's not efficient to do that? (i.e. to perform some demanding task to restructure the array). What would be the best thing to treat the rows with common group/department/team as the same row?

Comment: Use the combination of group/department/team as key for a new array, then you can easily group your values under that. Use `array_values` afterwards, to reset the keys to a zero-based numeric index.

Comment: I would suggest you to directly edit your SQL query in this way. You can use `GROUP BY` clause and use an aggregate function on columns not in the `GROUP BY` clause. Here a link to the doc on MySQL aggregate functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a requirement to summarize individual records into groups. The data needs to be reformatted in each group.

Method: By using a 'read ahead' technique we can remove the need to test each record to find out whether to add it to the current group or start a new group. The data is already ordered by team. We just need to iterate over each complete group in turn and append to the output.

The main point about the 'read ahead' technique is that read the next record immediately after you have processed it. This normally means that you cannot use a `foreach` loop as you often need to read a record before the end of the loop.

The code provided has O(n) runtime.

Note the code is commented to try and make it clear what is happening. The code is very basic PHP. It should work on all versions 5.6 and above I have tested it on 8.1.12.

Test: https://onlinephp.io/c/f8e59

```
<?php

$inputList = loadTestData();

print_r($inputList);

// -------------------------------------------------
//  Output - Team data by:  Group - Department - Team
// ------------------------------------------------- 
$outputList = array();
 
 
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  State
// 
// $currentTeamKey: This is the full key of the current team being processed
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$groupTeamKey = [];

// The current team record being processed
$currentTeamDetails = null;

// -------------------------------------------------
//  o Initialize Iterator
//  o Read Ahead 
// ------------------------------------------------- */
reset($inputList);

$currentTeamDetails = current($inputList); // always have a record to process

// -------------------------------------------------
//  Control
// -------------------------------------------------

while ($currentTeamDetails !== false) { // end of input?
    
    // Process ONE Team completely -- there must be at least one record in the group and it is ready to process 
    $groupTeamKey = getTeamKey($currentTeamDetails);
    $groupTeamData = [];

    // accumulate all the team data for the current team
    while (   $currentTeamDetails !== false // end of input
           && $groupTeamKey === getTeamKey($currentTeamDetails)) { 
        
        // Do not need to know the names of the data columns or the number of them.
        $groupTeamData[] = getTeamDataRow($currentTeamDetails, $groupTeamKey);
        $currentTeamDetails = next($inputList); // read ahead
    }
    
    // add the team data to the current key and append to the output
    $groupTeamKey['data'] = $groupTeamData;
    $outputList[] = $groupTeamKey;
}
// -------------------------------------------------
print_r($outputList);
exit;

// -------------------------------------------------
//  subroutines
// ------------------------------------------------- 

// -------------------------------------------------
//  Team Full Key: <group> <dept> <team>
// 
function getTeamKey(array $teamDetails = null)
{
    return  [ 'group' => $teamDetails['group'], 
             'department' => $teamDetails['department'],
             'team' => $teamDetails['team'],
            ];
}

// -------------------------------------------------
//  Team Data as 1 row 
//  Assume you don't know the data column names but you do know the keys!
// 
function getTeamDataRow(array $teamDetails, array $currentTeamKey)
{
    $allDataRows = array_diff_assoc($teamDetails, $currentTeamKey);
    
    $dataRow = []; 
    foreach ($allDataRows as $key => $value) {
        $dataRow[$key] = $value;
    }       
    
    return $dataRow;
}

//-------------------
// Test Data
//
function loadTestData()
{

return [
    0 => [
        'group' => "g1",
        'department' => "d1",
        'team' => null,
        'data_col1' => "some_data1",     
        'data_col2' => "some_data2",
    ],
    1 => [
        'group' => "g1",
        'department' => "d1",
        'team' => null,
        'data_col1' => "some_data3",
        'data_col2' => "some_data4",     
    ],
    2 => [
        'group' => "g1",
        'department' => "d1",
        'team' => "t3",
        'data_col1' => "some_data5",
        'data_col2' => "some_data6",
    ],
    3 => [
        'group' => "g4",
        'department' => "d6",
        'team' => "t11",
        'data_col1' => "some_data7",
        'data_col2' => "some_data8",    
    ],
];
}
```